# Create new empty directory tree from existing tree with files

Tags: linux, command-line, shell

I have a large directory tree with lots of files.

I would like to re-create the directory structure in a new location, but only the directories, not the files.

I've checked `cp`'s man page, but don't see an argument that will help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" /.../SOURCE /.../DESTINATION
```

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: This is explained in `man rsync` (see section "INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES"). The option `-f` adds a filter. `"+ */"` includes all directories, the following `"- *"` excludes everything else.

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p ~/to/{} \;
```

Taken from @whitequark's answer to to this question: [Copy directory structure without copying files, on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/171629/copy-directory-structure-without-copying-files-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Don't suppose there's a way to do this whilst maintaining attributes?

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is use the `tree` which is pretty handy and navigating directory trees based on its strong options. There are options for directory only, exclude empty directories, exclude names with pattern, include only names with pattern, etc. Check out `man tree`

**Advantage**: you can edit or review the list, or if you do a lot of scripting and create a batch of empty directories frequently

**Approach**: create a list of directories using `tree`, use that list as an arguments input to `mkdir`

```
tree -dfi --noreport > some_dir_file.txt
```

`-dfi` lists only directories, prints full path for each name, makes tree not print the indentation lines,

`--noreport` Omits printing of the file and directory report at the end of the tree listing,  just to make the output file not contain any fluff

**Then go to the destination where you want the empty directories and execute**

```
xargs mkdir < some_dir_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this as have hit a similar need. With a new enough version of rsync, that's your best bet.

If you don't have a recent version of rsync, then this does the trick:

```
find path/to/source -type -d -exec mkdir path/to/dest/'{}' \; -exec chown --reference='{}' path/to/dest/'{}' \; -exec chmod --reference='{}' path/to/dest/'{}' \;
```

(A variant of this can be used for permission mirroring)